# iOS: IBAction/Private methods -- why declare in .m under @interface?

Tags: ios, objective-c

What's the purpose for declaring `IBActions` or private methods in `.m` file under `@interface?`

Xcode seems to compile fine if I put the methods anywhere in `.m` file without the declaration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

More recent versions of Clang parse a little more. The compiler no longer needs to see the method declaration before use within an `@implementation` *in this case* because it knows the `@implementation` will close in the same translation (using `@end`). So it's just there for your convenience, but it's still quite recent and a lot of code was written before it was introduced.

Thus, the declaration is no longer necessary. It's of course still valid, so you can add it if you must support older toolchains or if you prefer to have its declaration in the `@interface ()`.